# ImageMagick converting the same image multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, process, imagemagick

I notice a slowdown in my server when using ImageMagick to resize some photos. Doing a `htop` shows that there are several similar `convert` commands (7) being executed at the same time on the same image. Is this normal for ImageMagick, or did my code somehow execute Imagemagick's `convert` mulitple times on the same image?

I am using ImageMagick `ImageMagick 6.7.9-6 2012-09-18`.

[image]

**convert --version**

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.9-6 2012-09-18 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

**Additional Info**

- There are 16 cores on the CentOS 6.3 i686 system.
- Typical input image file is about 10-100KB.
- The number of duplicate (not just similar) commands range from 2-16.

**Logging**

The log shows that there are no duplicate calls to `convert` to resize the same image twice.

Comment: Its really hard to see the above image. However, I would suggest logging the requests from your PHP script in a text file and just make sure there aren't any multiple entries in there with approx the same time.

Comment: Updated the post with link to a larger image

Comment: It does seem like that the same command is being executed multiple times with short intervals, though I am not Linux expert. It might be worth the effort to put in some logging right before the code calling the imagemagick conversion to narrow down what exactly is happening.

Comment: _or did my code somehow execute Imagemagick's convert mulitple times on the same image?_ - How should we know?  There's no code to look at.

Comment: +1 for Sean Bright! -- Also: *"several similar `convert` commands at the same time"*: how many is 'several' **exactly**?! How many CPU (cores) does this system have? How 'similar' **exactly**, what are the differences within this similarity?! What are the parent:child relationships between these similar commands?! How big is your input image?! -- Please also report the **full** output of `convert -version`.

Comment: The system has 16 cores. Using filtering in `htop`, I can see up to 16 similar (well, not just similar, they are exactly the same if u look at the screenshot posted). The convert command is exactly the same, including the input and output file. Sometimes I just see 2, but there may be more as my screen can only show so many results

Comment: So my assumption that `no. of cores == no. of quasi-simultaneous processes` seems to be rather valid. (You just do not always *see* all processes, because they may be too short-lived...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, one needs more details.

- *"... several similar convert commands at the same time..."*: how many is 'several' exactly?!
- How many CPU (cores) does this system have?
- How 'similar' exactly, what are the differences within this similarity?!
- What are the *parent:child* relationships between these similar commands?! (`pstree` command)
- How big is your typical input image?!

Please also report the full output of `convert -version`.

This seems to be a web service, guessing from the input JPEG's directory that can be seen in the screenshot. *Are you sure that there are not several convert commands started by the web service for every upload? -- Are you sure that the web service isn't contacted multiple times by the web *client* for every image to be converted?*

---

**Update:**

If your `convert -version` reports as one feature `OpenMP`, then your ImageMagick is multi-threaded, enabling it to simultaneously run multiple threads to process one large image. This can increase efficiency very greatly when it comes to process *large* image files. (But it can slow down overall performance greatly too, if you process many small files...)

My guess is that you don't see multiple (16) concurrent *processes* in the `htop` output, but multiple (16) concurrent execution *threads*.

For the typical use case of processing small files, you should try it with automatic multi-threading disabled, by setting this environment variable:

```
MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1
```

You can also *benchmark* your ImageMagick command to get closer to the optimal number of threads to be used. Adding [`-bench iterations`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#bench) prints the elapsed time and efficiency for one or more threads of the specific command:

```
convert                                        \
  -bench 40                                    \
   /home/photos/public_html/2012/0926/some.jpg \
  -resize 300                                  \
   null:
```

Your ImageMagick 6.7.9 is able to apply progressive threading while benchmarking a command. (It doesn't make much sense to test with `-bench` in non-OpenMP installations...)

See also [this discussion in the official ImageMagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20012).

Comment: I updated the answers to your questions in the original post. What do you mean by a web service? The server is hosting a website that does frequent down-sizing of photos submitted to it. I logged call to `convert` and it appears that only 1 call is made per image resized.

Comment: You run a website/server where you can upload/submit photos? The website/server down-sizes the photos it received? -- That's what some  people call a "web service"...

Comment: The website is much more than that, but Ok its a web service! :)